# If i compared the instance variable of class with the object what will it compare?

Tags: java

```
public class Notepad {
    private String name;
    private int year;
 
    public Notepad(String name, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null || this.getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (object == this) {
            return true;
        }

        Notepad compared = (Notepad) object;

        return this.name.equals(compared);
    }
}
```

```
Notepad basics = new Notepad("Equals basics", 2000);
Notepad advanced = new Notepad("Equals advanced", 2001);

System.out.println(basics.equals(basics));
System.out.println(basics.equals(advanced));
System.out.println(basics.equals(new Notepad("Equals basics", 2000)));
System.out.println(basics.equals(new Notepad("Equals basics", 2001)));
```

In the above code at the last two lines when i compare the basics object it returns false.In the equals method when i check this.name.equals(compared) what does it actually compares?

Comment: You're comparing a string `this.name` with the Notepad object reference `compared`. Perhaps what you meant was `this.name.equals(compared.name)` ?

Comment: Are you aware that you are comparing apples and oranges here? You are comparing a `String`, `this.name` with a `Notepad`. The result will always be "they are not equal".

Comment: @Joel I meant return this.name.equals(compared) only i just wanted to know what this.name will be compared with in the compared object?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes i am aware but what a string will be compared with in the Notepad?

Comment: What do you mean by "what `this.name`"? There is only one `this.name` and you can see what it is by printing it out using `System.out.println`. Do you mean "what exactly happens when I compare a string with a `Notepad`?"?

Comment: Yes exactly what happens when i compare a string with a Notepad object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return this.name.equals(compared);
```

Here you are comparing `name` field of `NotePad` object with the object of `NotePad`.

You should compare with the name field of the `compared`

```
return this.name.equals(compared.name);
```

What happened when compare String with `NotePad` object ?

Doc for String `equals` method

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
> and only if the argument is not null and **is a String object** that
> represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

So as comparing `Notpad` object is not a String object it will return false.

Comment: Ok thank but what the name will be compared with in the notepad object?

Answer (score 1):

`this.name` will not be compared to anything in the `Notepad` object. Similarly to your `Notepad.equals` method, the `String.equals` will check if the object supplied is not null first, and then if it is of an appropriate class, that is a `String`. A `Notepad` is not a `String` so here the comparison ends. No members of the given object are tested.

Answer (score 0):

`this.name` returns String which is an object.

You are comparing `this.name` with object `compared` of class Notepad. If you want to compare the names use:

`this.name.equals(compared.name)`

If you want to have the same condition return true, override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of Project class.

`equals()` returns true only if int value returned by `hashCode()`method for both the objects is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Use getClass() method to compare Objects...
I hope this code will help you...

```
public class Notepad {

    private String name;
    private int year;

    public Notepad(String name, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null || this.getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (object.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
            return true;
        }

        Notepad compared = (Notepad) object;

        return object.equals(compared);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Notepad basics = new Notepad("Equals basics", 2000);
        Notepad advanced = new Notepad("Equals advanced", 2001);

        System.out.println(basics.equals(basics));
        System.out.println(basics.equals(advanced));
        System.out.println(basics.equals(new Notepad("Equals basics", 2000)));
        System.out.println(basics.equals(new Notepad("Equals basics", 2001)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you want to compare String name should use this one,return this.name.equals(compared.name);